# C# command prompt output

Tags: c#, .net

I need to use a command prompt in my project. Everything is ok, but the output is not what I want. If I do this:

```
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd","/c dir c:\\test");
        info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        info.CreateNoWindow = true;
        info.UseShellExecute = false;
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = info;
        p.Start();
        string iii = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        textBox1.Text = iii;
```

The result is ok. Exactly as I want. But I also need to send some more commands. So I am doing this:

```
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd");
        info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        info.CreateNoWindow = true;
        info.UseShellExecute = false;
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = info;
        p.Start();
        StreamWriter write = p.StandardInput;
        write.WriteLine("dir c:\\test");
        write.Close();
        string iii = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        textBox1.Text = iii;
```

But the result is not like before. It's giving the path and everything in cmd, which I don't want. I need only the result from the command prompt and nothing else. Hope someone can help.  Thanks for reading my problem.

Comment: Well, I'm assuming you are referring to "dir c:\\test", which is simple to explain: you are writing it out yourself. Pass that via /c like you were before.

Comment: thanks for reply i did as you say but with this blank output..

Answer (score 0):

You have shown an implementation for something you want to do, and posed the question in terms of "why does my implementation not do what I expect". If we can take a step back and let us know "what I need is ..." (WINI) then we can (I think) give you a real answer.

For example:

If I take the WINI as "I need a directory listing of 'c:\test'" then I would say create a real simple little console app that gives you the raw data you want. The rest is formatting, think separation of concerns.

You then have a probe app that can give you whatever you like in a format best for you. You then use parser to parse the output.

So your little console app can do something like:

```
    public class Hyperthetical
{
    public void MyDemoCall(string root)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-- start --");
        GiveMeADirectoryListingAsIWantIt(root)
        Console.WriteLine("-- end --");
    }

    public void GiveMeADirectoryListingAsIWantIt(string directory)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Folder '{0}':", directory);

        foreach (var filePath in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory))
        {
            var fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
            Console.WriteLine("File: '{0}', {1}", fileInfo.Name, fileInfo.Length);
        }

        foreach (var subFolders in System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(directory))
        {
            GiveMeADirectoryListingAsIWantIt(subFolders);
        }
    }
}
```

Not a direct answer, but just maybe the real answer.

Comment: Mind you ... I'm not asking the other question ... why get a list of files this way?